# How to show processing ajax send?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, process

My function have for loop and once loop it's output percent of that loop. It's look like this:

```
function checkisset($v){
        foreach ($variable as $key=>$value)
            if($v==$value) echo $key/count($variable);
    }
```

and in client i want to show process of loop.

Ex: count($varibale)=10; First time in loop it will be 10%; and when 100% will run success function.

How can i do it??
Tks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

To update your webpage dynamically, you have to establish communication between the client and the server, and send updates.

One way to send updates is "[Server sent events](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp)". Another is "forever frame", where the page opens javascript link to the server and the server sends javascript statements over time.

In either case, you loop with updates will be a separate resource from the main page that you intend to update.